# Does a random matrix tend to be square and symmetric?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Random matrix theory defines a random matrix to be a matrix whose elements are random variables.

Given that Marcenko-Pastur initially devoted their distribution function to researching the covariance matrix (or was it correlation?), is this an indication that random matrix theory especially focuses on random matrices that are square and symmetric? If or if not, what makes square, symmetric matrices more important or practical to study

Comment: What all questions one might be interested in about a random matrix? One may ask about the distributions of eigenvalues, determinant, norm etc.. For a square matrix, we can ask all these questions. Symmetric (or hermitian) matrices make the analysis much easier. But nonetheless, people have studied the rectangular matrices. For example, Versheynin and Rudelson studied the singular values of rectangular matrices. I think one reason why square matrices were studied more is that square matrix ensembles arise in many other processes (for example in percolation).